# Line Integral where C is Line Segment

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral

$$ \oint\limits_C xe^y \mathrm ds  \;\text{where C is the line segment from (-1,2) to (1,1).}$$

My answer was $\sqrt{5}e(e-3)$. Did I get this right?

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to post steps of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is slightly different:
If you let $x=-1+2t$ and $y=2-t$ for $0\le t\le 1$,

I think you get the integral $$\int_0^1 (-1+2t)e^{2-t}\sqrt5 dt,$$
and then you can integrate by parts.

Comment: Yes that is the integral that I got, but my final answer was e*sqrt(5)*(e-3)

Comment: I'm sorry -- I got the same answer as you, but I think I didn't read the original answer you had correctly.